# how can i handle an exception site wide in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, exception

I am receiving this error in my application when I try to simulate someone tampering with my form...

```
Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.
```

I understand why it happens, what it protects me from and I want it to stay in place.
What I would like to do is handle it better. Display a better message to say there is a problem with your input or similar rather than this .net crash.

Is there a way I can catch this exception and handle it in my web.config file in a similar way to status errors?

e.g

```
<customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="Errors/GenericErrorPage.aspx">
      <error statusCode="403" redirect="Errors/NoAccess.htm" />
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="Errors/FileNotFound.htm" />
    </customErrors>
```

Comment: IMHO you should handle it as close to the source as possible but there is always the option to [handle uncaught exceptions](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/error-handling/web-api-global-error-handling) - just google for it - there are quite a few places where you can hook those up

Comment: thanks for the comment and link. we have lots of old forms on a long running webfroms project that has doesn't really have enough exception handling... it would be nice to handle en masse for this particular issue!

Comment: Giving an attacker a detailed error message is very near the top of the list of things not to do.

Comment: you are right :) not trying to give out details - just want to avoid a crash. however if something untoward is happening i'd rather not be helpful by giving them a nice error page.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I did some error logging. Found this exception produced a 500 error. I can handle this in the webconfig with a generic redirect that will suit my needs.

Like so:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Errors/GenericErrorPage.aspx">
     <error statusCode="500" redirect="Errors/IllegalErrorPage.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

Thanks to those who took the time to comment.